# Ontology on Protegè 4.2(ubuntu 12.04,64 bit)

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, protege

I'm learning how to build an ontology with protegè. I followed the tutorial about pizza but after creating class, subclass, etc when I use the reasoner Racer 2.0 it founds this problem:

> ParseException.encountnered: "error" at line 8,column 1
>   Was expecting one of:
>   "nil"...
>   "t"....

This is the xml_code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
<!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
<!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
<!ENTITY owl2xml "http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2-xml#" >
<!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
<!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
<!ENTITY pizzatutorial "http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#" > ]>

<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#"
 xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:owl2xml="http://www.w3.org/2006/12/owl2-xml#"
 xmlns:pizzatutorial="http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about=""/>



<!--   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Object Properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#hasBase -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#hasBase">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;FunctionalProperty"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Pizza"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#PizzaBase"/>
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="#hasIngredient"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="#isBaseOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#hasIngredient -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#hasIngredient">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;TransitiveProperty"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#hasTopping -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#hasTopping">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#Pizza"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#PizzaTopping"/>
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="#hasIngredient"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="#isToppingOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#isBaseOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#isBaseOf">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Pizza"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#PizzaBase"/>
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="#isIngredientOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#isIngredientOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#isIngredientOf">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;TransitiveProperty"/>
    <owl:inverseOf rdf:resource="#hasIngredient"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#isToppingOf -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#isToppingOf">
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#Pizza"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#PizzaTopping"/>
    <rdfs:subPropertyOf rdf:resource="#isIngredientOf"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Classes
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#AmericanHotPizza -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#AmericanHotPizza">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#JalapenoPepperTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#MozzarellaTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#TomatoTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#PepperoniTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#NamedPizza"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#AmericanPizza -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#AmericanPizza">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#TomatoTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#PepperoniTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#MozzarellaTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#NamedPizza"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#AnchovyTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#AnchovyTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#SeafoodTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#CaperTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#CaperTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#VegetableTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#CheeseTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#CheeseTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#PizzaTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#DeepPanBase -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#DeepPanBase">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#PizzaBase"/>
    <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="#ThinAndCrispyBase"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#GreenPepperTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#GreenPepperTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#PepperTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#HamTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#HamTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#MeatTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#JalapenoPepperTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#JalapenoPepperTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#PepperTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#MargheritaPizza -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#MargheritaPizza">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#TomatoTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#MozzarellaTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#NamedPizza"/>
    <rdfs:comment
        >A pizza that has only TomatonTopping and Mozzarella</rdfs:comment>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#MeatTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#MeatTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#PizzaTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#MozzarellaTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#MozzarellaTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#CheeseTopping"/>
    <owl:disjointWith rdf:resource="#ParmezanTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#MushroomTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#MushroomTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#VegetableTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#NamedPizza -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#NamedPizza">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#Pizza"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#OliveTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#OliveTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#VegetableTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#OnionTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#OnionTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#VegetableTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#ParmezanTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#ParmezanTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#CheeseTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#PepperTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#PepperTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#VegetableTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#PepperoniTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#PepperoniTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#MeatTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#Pizza -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#Pizza">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasBase"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#PizzaBase"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#PizzaBase -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#PizzaBase"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#PizzaTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#PizzaTopping"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#PrawnTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#PrawnTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#SeafoodTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#RedPepperTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#RedPepperTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#PepperTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#SalamiTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#SalamiTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#MeatTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#SeafoodTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#SeafoodTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#PizzaTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#SohoPizza -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#SohoPizza">
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#TomatoTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#ParmezanTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#OliveTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <owl:equivalentClass>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="#hasTopping"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="#MozzarellaTopping"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </owl:equivalentClass>
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#NamedPizza"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#SpicyBeefTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#SpicyBeefTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#MeatTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#ThinAndCrispyBase -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#ThinAndCrispyBase">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#PizzaBase"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#TomatoTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#TomatoTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#VegetableTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#TunaTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#TunaTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#SeafoodTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/marcello/ontologies/2015/4/pizzatutorial.owl#VegetableTopping -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="#VegetableTopping">
    <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#PizzaTopping"/>
</owl:Class>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// General axioms
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->

<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#HamTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#PepperoniTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#SalamiTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#SpicyBeefTopping"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#Pizza"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#PizzaBase"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#PizzaTopping"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#GreenPepperTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#JalapenoPepperTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#RedPepperTopping"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#AnchovyTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#PrawnTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#TunaTopping"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#CaperTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#MushroomTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#OliveTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#OnionTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#PepperTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#TomatoTopping"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#CheeseTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#MeatTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#SeafoodTopping"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#VegetableTopping"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;AllDisjointClasses"/>
    <owl:members rdf:parseType="Collection">
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#AmericanHotPizza"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#AmericanPizza"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#MargheritaPizza"/>
        <rdf:Description rdf:about="#SohoPizza"/>
    </owl:members>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: Use another reasoner and see if the error is reproachable. I ran your ontology with Fact++ and HermiT and it ran smoothly. Although, you have 4 classes that are unsatisfiable. If you want a reason for the unsatisfiablity, you need to edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: ok thanks for the help.
It works,i don't know why racer gives problems.
Anyway i made another question called semantic_map-knowrob.
Could you solve that problem too??